# How do I build a SQL Statement that selects multiple rows and sums the amount?

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I'm recently working with DB/2 for an AS/400 and I ran across something that I am not really strong at.  I have written this SQL Statement to bring back all of the fields that will bring back all the results dated from 4/30/2012 to 4/30/2013  I've hard-coded the values for now:

```
SELECT PPOLNO, PPRMPD FROM PFNTLPYMTH WHERE (PYEAR >=2012 AND PMONTH <=4 AND PDAY >=1)
```

The table has multiple PPOLNO values that are the same, and the same with the PPRMPD field.

I'd like to be able to return a single PPOLNO and a sum of all of the dollar amounts.  For example:

***PPOLNO | PPRMPD***

```
1     |  500.00
1     |  500.00
2     |  250.00
1     |  100.00
3     |  5000.00
```

I want to write a sql query that will bring back just:

***PPOLNO | PPRMPD***

```
1     | 1100.00
2     | 250.00
3     | 5000.00
```

But I am not sure what to add on to the SQL Statement to make it so.  I can get a distinct list of PPOLNO, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about getting the sum in the same query (if it's even possible).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try:

```
SELECT PPOLNO, SUM(PPRMPD) PPRMPD FROM PFNTLPYMTH GROUP BY PPOLNO
```

and you can add necessary where conditions for the query.

Comment: I cannot believe that I forgot about GROUP BY:  I think I have do to the same thing across 3 separate tables and join them together, which will require some additional SQL.  I had asked this under a bad assumption of mine.  It was only until 'now' that my boss said "Oh I forgot to tell you there are 3 tables in total"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PPOLNO, SUM(PPRMPD) AS SUM FROM PFNTLPYMTH WHERE (PYEAR >=2012 AND PMONTH <=4 AND PDAY >=1) GROUP BY PPOLNO
```

Should do it

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty straight-forward.

```
SELECT  PPOLNO, SUM(PPRMPD) AS TotalAmount
FROM    TableName
-- WHERE  ..add conditions here...
GROUP   BY PPOLNO
```